# Alternative to Google Sites permitting custom domains?

Tags: google-workspace, google-classic-sites

Is there any alternative to [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com/) that permits custom domain hosting, and a modern selection of templates and GUI web editing tools? I still suggest to people to Google Sites, but the product has really stagnated lately and I'm wondering what else is out there.

Answer (score 4):

[Weebly](http://weebly.com) is awesome. It has a wonderfully intuitive website creator.

I don't know if they have kept adding features at the same pace they did a year ago,  but their applications is quite well-rounded and they have a lot of templates to choose from (+ the editor).

Hope this helps!

Comment: weebly is a scam... avoid if at all possible.

Comment: why do you say so? I haven't had any negative experience with it...

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Weebly. You might also take a look at [SquareSpace](http://www.squarespace.com/), very similar.